# upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04: no mouse, no connection, icon missings

Tags: networking, upgrade, tethering

I just upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and, even though all the steps seemed to have completed seamlessly until restart, once I rebooted I got:

- no mouse icon (touchpad or external USB mouse)
- no network interface apart from the **loopback** interface (I should have both wired and wireless connections available)
- application icons missing in `gnome`

Now, I can connect the computer to the Internet via **USB tethering** through my cellphone, but it just doesn't see the connection.

How do do it from a terminal?

(Strangely, there is no `network-manager`)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 has reached End of Life, and so the updates necessary to do a successful upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 are no longer supported. You should have backed up your personal files and done a clean install. Doing a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 should take about 30 minutes plus whatever time it takes you to backup all your personal files before you start the clean install of Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: So is there really no way to upgrade without reformatting everything?

Comment: The OS says the installed release is 12.04, but it seems that it messed up a lot of stuff in the process.

Comment: You can even do a clean install of Ubuntu without reformatting your /home directory if your /home directory is on a separate partition. I've done it myself that way without losing any data. Two things you should know about doing it that way is (1) that the manual partitioning is a bit complicated to figure out, and (2) you should always backup your personal files anyway, no matter what type of install you decide to do.